# List of acronyms (glossaries package) seen as a subsection, not as a chapter

Tags: pdftex, glossaries, acronyms

I'm using the `glossaries` package to have a list of acronyms in my article. However, the list of acronyms is seen in my TOC as a chapter, not as the subsection as it should.

I tried with this: `\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{\protect\numberline{2.2}Acronyms}` but no effect. Here's what it looks like now:

[image]

But I would like to see only one reference to acronyms in TOC, and it should be seen as a subsection `2.2` of section `B`. How can I do this? Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[toc, acronym]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newacronym{cpu}{CPU}{Central Processing Unit}
\newacronym{isp}{ISP}{Internet Service Provider}
\newacronym{dss}{DSS}{Decision Support System}
\newacronym{aes}{AES}{Advanced Encryption Standard}

\begin{document}      

\tableofcontents

\section{A1}

\subsection{A1}

\gls{aes}

\subsection{A2}

\gls{cpu}, \gls{aes}

\subsection{A3}

\section{B}
\subsection{B1}

\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{\protect\numberline{2.2}Acronyms}
\printglossaries 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While I typed this, the same answer was posted as comment; so see this as a example of code:

You can change this by using the option keys. To change the TOC-level of your glossaries use section=section/subsection/chapter as package option and to have it numbered use numberedsection as option for printglossary[]. This should give you the desired result.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[toc, acronym, 
    section=subsection,%standard:chapter
    ]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newacronym{cpu}{CPU}{Central Processing Unit}
\newacronym{isp}{ISP}{Internet Service Provider}
\newacronym{dss}{DSS}{Decision Support System}
\newacronym{aes}{AES}{Advanced Encryption Standard}

\begin{document}      

\tableofcontents

\section{A1}

\subsection{A1}

\gls{aes}

\subsection{A2}

\gls{cpu}, \gls{aes}

\subsection{A3}

\section{B}
\subsection{B1}

%\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{\protect\numberline{2.2}Acronyms}
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,title=List of Acronyms,toctitle=List of Acronyms, numberedsection] 

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 I'll delete my comment. (I didn't have time to write a full answer.)